# Any hints about loop invariant of weird loop?

Tags: loop-invariants

I have this tiny program for finding largest prime divisor (taken from Code Review Stackexchange and written by user Altinak:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74792):

Here is my try to write it in pseudocode:

```
GLOBAL VARIABLE highest;

// This function takes parameters n and f with 1 <= n and 2 <= f.
// It returns n with f factored out of it.
// Also, if f divides n and if f > h then it replaces h with f

factorize(n, f) {
    if (n < f)
        return n
    while (n mod f == 0) {
        n = n / f
        if (f > highest)
            highest = f
    }
    return n
}

find(n) {
    highest = 1

    n = factorize(n, 2)
    n = factorize(n, 3)

    if (n >= 5) {
        i = 5
        while (i * i <= n) {
            n = factorize(n, i)
            n = factorize(n, i + 2)
            i = i + 6
        }
    }
    if (n == 1)
        return highest
    else
        return n
}
```

But the `while` loop in the function `find` is harder than ones I have seen before - its number of iterations aren't easy to calculate before the loop, as the variable `n` from the condition `i * i <= n` changes in the loop body.

Right now I feel like I'm stuck and have no idea how to write the loop invariant for this loop, but I will try to think of something. Meanwhile, big thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: Start with pre- and post-conditions for `factorize()`.

Comment: `factorize()` takes parameters `n` and `f`  with `1 <= n` and `2 <= f`. It returns `n` with `f` factored out of it, and also, if `f` divides `n` and if `f > h` then it replaces `h` with `f`.

Smth like this. Should I add it to the post?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: Well. Now it should be easy to state a precondition for the loop. What invariants does the loop keep?

Comment: I believe that I have no idea. Maybe I'm over-complicating it, dunno.

Comment: Well, the calculated `n` (after each iteration) is less or equal to starting `n` before the loop. But that does not give us enough information to prove correctness of all algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invariant says that the current value of `n` is the initial value of `n` divided by all its factors in the trial sequence 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31... until `i`. Some of the numbers in this sequence are not primes, but their factors have been previously processed and simplified, so equivalently, we have `n` divided by all its prime factors until `i`.

The number of iterations of the while loop equals the number of elements of the sequence 5², 7², 11², 13², 17², 19²... that do not exceed `n[5]`, `n[7]`, `n[11]`... respectively, where `n[m]` denotes the value of `n` after all factors until `m` have been removed. So the number of iterations is also the number of elements of the sequence until the highest prime factor.

In addition, the function `factorize` executes a number of divisions equal to the multiplicity of the prime factor `f` in the number `n`. When `f` is not a prime, the function returns immediately because its factors have already been consumed; the iteration count is the same for the initial and current `n`.

Hence, the total complexity will be like the sum of the multiplicities of the prime factors of `n`, plus the highest prime factor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What do you mean by (total) complexity? (I understand the 1st and 3rd paragraph, but anything else is over my head, it seems.)

Comment: @LessnessRandomness: I mean time complexity.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't a time complexity a different matter from the loop invariant? (I'm beginner, so apologies for noob questions.)

Comment: @LessnessRandomness: didn't you ask about the number of iterations ?

Comment: I believe that no. Loop invariant is smth completely different - it's a fact that holds before each iteration or smth like this and it is used when proving correctness of the program. My apologies about this misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh, I understand now what's the reason of this. I will try to use your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @LessnessRandomness "its number of iterations aren't easy to calculate". But how you doubt my understanding when I give you both the invariant and the complexity analysis ?!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, probably